# How is RHEL/centos different from Fedora package-wise/user-relevance-wise?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, open-source

What are the improvements that CentOS brings over Fedora?

So far I have only found this: [Changes in CentOS over RHEL](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7#head-d58ad86f1b5399bb36755532321b1df4f242a88c) and this: [What is RHEL?](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux)

But what improvements exactly does CentOS provide over Fedora? Does it have more features or improvements?

Edit: I have shortened the question to get a pointed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora is "bleeding edge", Red Hat Enterprise is "stable".  CentOS is a copy (except for licensed stuff and trademarked material) of Red Hat Enterprise.

The CentOS DVD holds the entire release; Fedora doesn't do that (reduces cost), assumes you install most packages over the network.

Further reading:

- [What's the difference between Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux?](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#What.27s_the_difference_between_Fedora_and_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux.3F)

Comment: But stable software doesn't add new stuff to existing source. Doesn't Red Hat add proprietary software to Fedora in RHEL?

Comment: Not really (proprietary software is licensed, which makes it unsuitable for Fedora).

Comment: What I meant was: Doesn't RHEL contain proprietary software? How does it then qualify as a stable version of Fedora when it adds other stuff?

Comment: It's **stable** because (a) Red Hat takes responsibility for testing and integration and (b) Red Hat controls (limits) changes to **all** of the components of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 0):

And Red Hat will sell you support for RHEL. It is aimed at the Enterprise user.

Comment: Does that mean Red Hat doesn't add software to Fedora?

Comment: Depends what you mean by add, I guess. Fedora is where software that will eventually get incorporated into RHEL first shows up. They used to be the same thing, Fedora was split off around 10 or 15 years ago. Think of Fedora as the development branch.

Comment: This was helpful.